# ListView entry has to be clicked twice for execution of code

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView inside a navigation bar, and when i click on one of the entries, a WebView opens a specific page. However, the second time i click on some other entry, the code is not executed. I have to click the entry twice to execute the code that OnItemClick performs.

Java:

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {
String[] cityArray = { "Agra ", "Ahmedabad ", "Alappuzha ", "Amritsar "};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
      final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
      final WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
      final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
      webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);        
      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, cityArray);
      list.setAdapter(adapter);

 web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }
    });
 web.loadData("<img src=\"http://s19.postimg.org/cm48n0noj/droidweather.jpg\" width=100%></img>", "text/html", "utf-8");
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        if (position == -1)
        {
            web.loadData("<img src=\"http://s19.postimg.org/cm48n0noj/droidweather.jpg\" width=100%></img>", "text/html", "utf-8");
        }
        if (position == 0)
        {
            web.loadUrl("http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=27.18&lon=78.02&name=Agra&units=uk");
        }  
        if (position == 1)
        {
            web.loadUrl("http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=23.03&lon=72.58&name=Ahmedabad&units=uk");
        }
    }

});
}
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The Url i'm asking the WebView to load is an embed url. It is not updated after tapping a separate ListView.

Solution was to add a web.reload(); or by just loading the Url twice. This purges the displayed data in Webview and it is displayed in one click.